# How to work out the value for NSAttributedString.Key.expansion?

Tags: swift, cocoa

need some help with this key.

If I have a NSAttributedString and I know its width is, say 295, I want expanded it to, say 300. How do I work out the value for NSAttributedString.Key.expansion to achieve this? The manual only says the value "indicating the log of the expansion factor to be applied to glyphs". I don't understand it.

Many thanks in advance.

Graham

Comment: This `Key.expansion` attribute is not about string width, it's about the wide scale. I don't know what your purpose is. In case you want to make, for example, a label width after setting an attribute, simply add a space " " at the end.

Comment: Isn't `NSAttributedString.Key.expansion` deprecated?

Comment: I found .kern does what I need. I am trying to implement an alternative way to justify a string in the text box. Instead of throw extra space between words (default for justified strings), I try to expand (or condense) the text string width to fit the Textbox width. I found .kern allows me to do this. In this case, the kern value will be the extra space divided by the number of characters in the string, then the new text string width will be equal to the width of the text box.